# How to take into account Time to live when planning capacity for cache cluster

Tags: caching, ignite, capacity-planning

I am working on setting up an apache ignite cluster for our project. For the capacity planning I using the guidelines provided here https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/capacity-planning

However the planning does not mention how the TTL of the cache record will affect the required memory. Can some one please help me in understanding how to take into account the TTL when planning for the cache capacity?

Comment: What do you mean? Overhead of the TTL measurement and storage? The page you're referring has a note that there is an overhead around 200bytes per entry - I think it includes the TTL tracking as well.

Comment: I am trying to come up with the memory usage caclulation that I can use to setup an ignite cluser for our use-cases. In the article , the sample calculation comes upto ~6GB . But I am not clear as to how this memory usage will change based on the TTL configuration. For EG: If I configure my TTL to 30 secs will my memory usage will still be 6GB or greater or smaller? I needed help in getting that clarified.

Comment: What kind of TTL do you mean? There's `page eviction`, `entry eviction` and `expiration`.